# Confusion when composing functions in Lambda expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

> [image]
>
> $$(\lambda x. x \text{ } x ) ( \lambda x . x \text{ } x )=  (\lambda x. x \text{ } x) ( \lambda x . x \text{ } x)$$
>
> [Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T8A89jgeTI&ab_channel=Computerphile)

I am a bit confused on how this composition was done. When I do it, I get:

$$ \lambda x. (\lambda x. x \text{ } x) (\lambda x . x \text{ } x)$$

On what basis do I drop the exterior most $\lambda x.$?

Comment: It's not composition - it's application.

Comment: the point is that when you write a $\lambda$-term $M \ N$ the "meaning" - which can be evaluated using $\beta$-reduction - is what might be written $M(N)$ in conventional function notation, not $M \circ N$ as you've interpreted it.

Comment: All this might be a bit obscured by the overuse of variable name $x$. Perhaps there would be a bit less confusion if you wrote $(\lambda x. x x)(\lambda y. y y)$ instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You drop the $\lambda x$ because that's just how beta reduction is defined: $(\lambda v.M)(N) \triangleright_\beta M[v/N]$. In your example, $v$ is $x$, $M$ is $xx$, and $N$ is $\lambda x. xx$.

The intuition is that once you applied the function to an argument, then the slot is filled and no longer open for substitution with yet another argument ad infinitum. The "$\lambda x.$" is like the "$f(x) = $" in something like "$f(x) = x^2$". Once you apply the function, $f(2)$, the result is equivalent to $4$ (the part behind the equivalence sign with $2$ substituted for $x$), and not a new function of the form $f(x)$.

Comment: Or "$x \mapsto$" in "$f : x \mapsto x^2$"